# Upgrading to the Google Maps Android API 2 monodroid

Tags: android, xamarin.android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have an android application that use Google Maps Android API Version 1 for its map. Now, I want to use Google Maps API Version 2 for on my application (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/) .

What is more quicker solution to upgrade my projects code to version 2? It looks that all codes changes. I have codes for changing center of map, adding overlays, changing zoomlevel, finding map bound lat/lng and etc.

And Also whether this API Also supports Android versions 2.3 or not?

Thanks

Comment: this is not really nice, what you have did right now.

Comment: @Emil Adz I do not understand what is not really nice? I just have question about quickest way for upgrading from api version 1 to 2. What is not nice?

Comment: what is not really nice is the fact, that you have accepted my answer as the answer that helped, then with no explanation un-accepted it and accepted another answer. this is not a nice behavior. wasn't my answer helpful to you in the first place?

Comment: @Hussein, I have an this answer as unaccepted in my rep history. This means that it was accepted before that. never mind, good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Maps v2 is completely different from Google Maps v2, so there probably won't be much code you can save / port over.

Google Maps v2 requires Android 2.2 or higher and Google Play services.

There is a [sample for Xamarin.Android](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/MapsAndLocationDemo_v2) up on Github. It targets Android 4.0 and higher but can be easily changed to support Android 2.2 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

The API v2 supports devices from 2.2.

I believe the quickest way to switch to v2 is by removing your `MapActivity`-based class and all code related to that and creating a new `FragmentActivity`-based.